# Using Laravel Socialite to connect facebook and validating user permissions

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

Currently I am creating website that allow user login by their facebook. and the website require their email.

the problem is how to facebook authorization with require their email.
but when the user doesn't give their email permission, how to cancel the authorization process.

*I know facebook docs tell me, that facebook was not guarantee we grab the user email. but how to cancel when the user does not allow their email in permission list*

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3
>
> email
>
> Provides access to the person's primary email address via the email
>   property on the user object.
>
> Do not spam users. Your use of email must comply with both Facebook
>   policies and with the CAN-SPAM Act.
>
> Note, even if you request the email permission it is not guaranteed
>   you will get an email address. For example, if someone signed up for
>   Facebook with a phone number instead of an email address, the email
>   field may be empty.
>
> Review Your app may use this permission without review from Facebook.

*when user disable their email permissions picture :*
[image: user disable their email permissions picture]

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]

I can using **user revoking permissions**.

see here :
[Using Laravel Socialite to Manage User socials setting (like pinterest at user settings page)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30611328/using-laravel-socialite-to-manage-user-socials-setting-like-pinterest-at-user-s/30649246#30649246)