# Using Laravel Socialite to Manage User socials setting (like pinterest at user settings page)

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

How to make unauthorization user social media like pinterest in settings page.

so the user can settings connect and disconnect their social media from our website.

*pinterest setting social picture page :*
[image: pinterest setting social picture]

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED] I see, I can using revoking permissions

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#revoking

my bad, not read docs carefully. hehehe